# How write an Xpath to get list of attributes (like Name) from Constants that do not have empty / no values?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
 <Constants>
     <Constant Name="ExchangeRates"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="Company">Test</Constant>
     <Constant Name="TopFrameScreenInputs"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="TopFrameBTScreenInputs"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="MidFrame1BTScreenInputs"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="MidFrame1ScreenInputs"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="MidFrame2ScreenInputs"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="MidFrame2BTScreenInputs"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="SpareScreenInPriceInputs1"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="SpareScreenInPriceInputs2"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="SpareScreenInPriceInputs3"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="SpareScreenOptionInputs1"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="SpareScreenOptionInputs2"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="SpareScreenOptionInputs3"></Constant>
     <Constant Name="ChildFormInputsLoopCounter">1</Constant>
    <Constant Name="ScreenChildMode">TEST</Constant>
  </Constants>
```

So, I am writing an xpath that gets names of constants, such "Company" and "ScreenChildMode" which do have values, and skip over values like "ExchangeRates" which have none.

So far, I have

`"/Specification/Constants[Constant!='']/Constant/attribute::Name"`

Any Suggestions? I know I want the value / atomic of "Constant" to be non-empty, which I would think would be [*!=''], but it does not quite work.
When I try this:
`"/Specification/Constants[Constant!='']/attribute::Name"`
It doesn't list any values.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: While asking an XPath question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XPath expression that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XPath processor and its conformance with the XPath standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Comment: +one for not perfect, but well formatted question...

Comment: The XPath operator `!=` can be surprising, and is usually best avoided. The test ($X != '') is true if $X contains a value that is not an empty string; if $X does not contain any values (if it's an empty sequence) then it returns false. It's usually better to write `not($X = '')`. In this case however, the boolean test `[text()]` as suggested by @YitzhakKhabinsky is better.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample XML, the following XPath expression will do it:

**XPath 1.0**

```
/Constants/Constant[text()]/@Name
```

**Output**

```
Company
ChildFormInputsLoopCounter
ScreenChildMode
```

Answer (score 0):

With `string-length()`, using `XPath1` (so compliant with `XPath` > 1):

```
'//Constant[string-length(text()) > 0]/@name'
```

```
Company
ChildFormInputsLoopCounter
ScreenChildMode
```

Comment: Very convoluted solution, though it will work.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with Constant-elements with insignificant whitespace you could also use:

```
'/Specification/Constants/Constant[normalize-space(text())]/@Name'
```